# Failed to parse URL with brackets, commas and spaces

Tags: bug

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [URL with ' ' (space) not working](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/81778/url-with-space-not-working)

I pasted the following URL into a comment, and SO failed to parse it correctly.

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase.html#insert(java.lang.String, java.lang.String, android.content.ContentValues)

The comment is in response to this question: https://stackoverflow.com/a/9158274/385478

Comment: Congratulations, Java, in constructing documentation URLs which continue to haunt us evermore.

Comment: As you can see it's also failed to parse it the body of the question too. Probably an issue with the brackets and/or commas.

Comment: And this is a dupe, by the way. _/lazy_

Comment: @ChrisF: I would blame the *spaces* in the URL over brackets and commas ;).

Comment: @Matt - If you copy the link address of the above link you get: `http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase.html#insert(java.lang.String` - note no comma at the end. However, the spaces probably don't help either.

Answer (score 2):

The URL is malformed; a valid form would be:

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase.html#insert%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20android.content.ContentValues%29

If you use the link icon to construct the link, it will massage the URL into a correct form: [example](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase.html#insert%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20android.content.ContentValues%29).

Answer (score 0):

On removing the spaces from the link the problem 'goes away' - but then you don't have *that* link precisely. You could, of course, alter ugly Java documentation inherited type links used there (and other places) to use `%20` for the spaces instead, which 'fixes' the link, but could be considered a laborious effort.

[Here's](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/13509/157071) an explanation of URL formatting using Markdown, but it doesn't cover this scenario. If it wasn't Monday I might have done so.